# Junit Ant Jenkins ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am running Junit Tests on Jenkins via ant, and I am getting really stuck with this one error.

Relevant parts of my ant file:

```
<!-- Get the Junit test files -->
<target name="getTest">
    <svn svnkit="false" javahl="false">
        <export srcUrl="${svn.junit}" destPath="${junit.dir}" />
    </svn>
</target>
<!-- Compile Junit Test Files -->
<target name="test-compile" depends="compileJava">
    <javac srcdir="${junit.dir}" target="1.6" source="1.6" destdir="${test.classes}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.classpath" />
            <pathelement location="${test.classes}" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- Run JUnit Tests -->
<target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit haltonfailure="no" failureproperty="failed">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.classpath" />
            <pathelement location="${test.classes}" />
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
    <fail message="TEST FAILER" if="failed" />
</target>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/junit-4.11.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/ant-junit-1.8.4.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${build.lib.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${source.dir}" />
</path>
```

The tests compile into test-classes folder and runs in test with console output:
`[junit] Test com.some.app.ProjectName.MyTestClass FAILED`

When you go to view the test in test results, it shows the stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.some.app.ProjectName.MyTestClass
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [junit documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) describes the batchtest operation as follows:

> Define a number of tests based on pattern matching.
>
> *batchtest* collects the included resources from any number of nested Resource Collections. It then generates a test class name for each resource that ends in *.java* or *.class*.

So this hints at an issue with the "test-compile" target, because what's missing is a class name derived from the following fileset:

```
<fileset dir="${junit.dir}">
    <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
</fileset>
```

Although the ANT file looks good, is there any chance you're missing the "package" declaration at the top of your Java source code? I got caught with that one once.... Look into the ${test.classes} directory an double-check that there are no matching class files.

Comment: Yea it was the package declaration. Thank you.